# Can't download from HP Website

Tags: windows-7, browser, download, website

I have a problem, and I have no idea where to start looking at a solution.

I have just installed a new copy of Windows 7 on a new computer, and I want to download drivers from [HP Driver](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=3442750&prodNameId=3442751&swEnvOID=4063&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=ma-78748-2).

The problem is that every time I try to download that file (or any other file in that site) I get errors like  "**No data received**" or "**Website cannot be displayed**"...

The weird part about it is that I have a laptop right next to me, and when I try to download from that, everything works fine, really... no problems.

I can't figure this out.

**Note**: This issue is only with HP site.

Comment: Try different browsers?

Comment: tried that, still happens

Answer (score 1):

The problem's seems to localised. As you said, it works here as well.

It could depend on a lot of things. Can't really say. You could try some of these:

1. Try to open the link in different browser (or in private/incognito mode)
2. Disconnect/reconnect your internet connection
3. Try to use Google's public DNS servers for dns (8.8.8.8) [`ipconfig /flushdns` later]
4. Disable javascript and/or cookies and try.

These are the basic things I try when a site seems slow.

Answer (score 1):

You say you can download from the same pages at HP, from a different computer?

> The weird part about it is that I have a laptop right next to me and when I try to download from that everything works fine, really... no problems.

Then what you should try, is downloading all the driver installation packages you need for the new installation with the laptop, putting them on a CD/DVD/USB Stick, and then installing them that way.  Your issue could even be due to using outdated NIC drivers that came with the Windows installation.

At any rate, it is a way available to you to download all the driver packages successfully.

Comment: THIS IS NOT A SOLUTION. not enough rep to downvote in this stack but this answer should be

Comment: It get's the job done without any side effects or crazy hacks, sounds like a pretty good solution to me.

Comment: If anything,user238729 solved the problem by providing the walk around , but this is still not an answer for the problem...

Comment: @gleeb downloading and installing the NIC drivers might solve the issue, since with a fresh install there are no necessary settings or configurations to avoid this.  Did you even try this to see if it worked?

Comment: I will try it and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

HP's driver site is notoriously slow.

Does a Refresh usually fix it?

I have to ask: are you comparing like-for-like between the laptops? i.e. Same Anti-Virus software, firewall software & status, same version of web browser, same network link speed?

When it fails to show the page, you should still get the address it was directing you to (eg. ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softlib/software11/COL31748/ma-78748-2/M1522series-win7-full-solution-EMEA2-v4.3.exe ). What happens if you change the ftp:// to http:// ?

Comment: when i added http:// before the link it worked. i still don't understand why. h ttp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softlib/software11/COL31748/ma-78748-2/M1522series-win7-full-solution-EMEA2-v4.3.exe works... any ideas?